# Submenu does not come on of top html controls and disappears on hover

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

I have created a menu and submenu as seen in the image (couldn't be uploaded due to restrictions). When I try to hover over submenu, the submenu shows up hiding behind the grid. Also, when I try to select a item in submenu it disappears. To summarise the submenu doesn't come on top of html controls. I have tested the menu independently and it works fine. Here is the css

```
   /* menu */
 .nav-bar {
    height:20px;
    width:100%;
}
.nav-bar .nav {
    list-style-type:none;
    background:#ccc;
}
.nav li {
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    font:bold 14px/38px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.nav li a {
    padding:0 22px;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#231f20;
    color:#66ccff;
}
.nav li a.activemenu {
    padding:0 22px;
    background-color:#231f20;
    color:#66ccff;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.nav li.spacer {
    background:url(../images/nav-spacer.jpg) left top no-repeat;
    width:2px;
    height:38px;
    padding:0;
}
.nav li span.arrow {
    margin:0;
    padding-left:5px;
    height:12px;
    font-size:11px;
}
/** sub nav **/
 ul.sub-nav {
    list-style-type:none;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background:#f2f2f2;
    border:solid 1px #bababa;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    padding:10px 0;
    margin-top:0px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #333;
}
ul.sub-nav li {
    float:none;
}
ul.sub-nav li a {
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
    font:normal 14px/26px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display:block;
}
ul.sub-nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#7f7f7f;
    color:#fff;
}
.nav li:hover ul.sub-nav {
    display:block;
}
ul.sub-nav span {
    position:absolute;
    top:-24px;
    left:20px;
    display:block;
}
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="nav-bar">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="http://10.90.48.58:5000/"> </a>
        </li>
        <li class="spacer"></li>
        <li> <a href="#"><span class="arrow"></span></a>

            <ul class="sub-nav">
                <li><a href="http://10.90.48.58:5000/nodes">Nodes</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://10.90.48.58:5000/facts">Facts</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://10.90.48.58:5000/reports">Reports</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://10.90.48.58:5000/metrics">Metrics</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://10.90.48.58:5000/query">Query</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `<li><a href="http://10.90.48.58:5000/"` missing a closing `>`...typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give `position`, make sure you set `z-index`!

```
ul.sub-nav {
    list-style-type:none;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background:#f2f2f2;
    border:solid 1px #bababa;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    padding:10px 0;
    margin-top:0px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #333;
    z-index: 10;
}
```